# Using CSS fixed positioning while already relative

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change [this Wordpress theme](http://www.themetrust.com/themes/hero).

The header has an relative position, but I want it to be fixed.
When I change this in the CSS it messes up the whole page.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this? Is there any way to make the header fixed while the position:relative stays that way?

Comment: Please add some more detail and code to this question; as it stands, I doubt it's properly answerable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title to fit better your question, and made your link clickable. To include code, just paste it in, select it, and press the "code" button `{}` on the toolbar.

Comment: Gael's answer seems correct

Answer (score 1):

Fixed position implies that the element gets out the normal positioning flow.
So you have to add these properties:

```
#header{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}  
#wrap{
  padding-top: 140px;
}
```